# Increase the size in Gmail, larger than normal but smaller than large

Tags: gmail

Would anyone please tell me how to adjust the font size in Gmail? When I copy content from somewhere, Gmail will keep the font size from that resource. How can I set my font size larger than normal but smaller than large and don't have to copy from other resources to get the desired font size?

Thank you so much!

Update: solved. You can create a template with a desired font in Gmail.

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center. Questions about Web Applications are out of scope here at Super User